# WPF: The ViewModel-type does not contain any accessible constructors

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am instantiating my repository in my `MainViewModel` and passing this instance to use in my child `ViewModel` (i.e. `CategoryViewModel`).  I am getting a

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error       The type "CategoryViewModel" does not include any accessible constructors.

The error is coming from my main window where I have declared the Category user control and setting the `DataContext` to `CategoryViewModel`:

```
<view:CategoryView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5">
    <view:CategoryView.DataContext>
        <viewModel:CategoryViewModel />
    </view:CategoryView.DataContext>
</view:CategoryView>
```

I am not getting this error when I don't have any parameters in the `CategoryViewModel` constructor so I know it has something to do with that but not exactly sure what is causing the problem. I would appreciate any advice. Below is my `MainViewModel` and `CategoryViewModel`.

```
public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IRepository _repo = new Repository();
    private CategoryViewModel _categoryViewModel;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _categoryViewModel = new CategoryViewModel(_repo);
    }
}

public class CategoryViewModel : BindableBase
{       
    private IRepository _repo;
    public List<Category> CategoryCollection { get; set; }

    public CategoryViewModel(IRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;            
       CategoryCollection = LoadCategory();

    }

    private List<Category> LoadCategory()
    {
        return _repo.GetAllCategories();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a no-args constructor

Comment: have you tried adding an empty constructor (no params)?

Comment: yes I did try adding an empty constructor and it works.  Not sure how to pass my repository object to the other viewmodel.  I guess I can use a messenger to send it.  Thought the constuctor would be a better way to go. Maybe not.

Comment: I solved this same error by realizing that my UserControl was named the same as a class already in my project.  In other words, you can check for CategoryViewModel.xaml and CategoryViewModel.cs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two options if you want a constructor with parameters: instantiate your view model in code behind, or use [ObjectDataProvider class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:
In **Control.Xaml**, I put this in the top level tag(Not sure how to convert it to the full xml notation)

```
  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=visuals:ControlPanelRadPaneVM, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

In **Control.Xaml.cs** I added a constructor accepting the context, marked it as Injection Constructor and assigned dataContext:

```
public partial class Shell : Window
{
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public Shell(ShellViewModel context)
    {
        DataContext = context;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

That's it. Now whenever I do a container.Resolve() I get them both. I've not seen any issues yet. but apparently it can be done.